# Converting Scala String to Xml in .xml.scala Template

Tags: java, string, scala, playframework, twilio-twiml

I am getting difficulties in converting Scala to xml

twiml.scala.xml

```
@(body:String)
<Response>
    <Say voice="alice">
    @body
    </Say>
</Response>
```

and body is `String` that contains "`</Say><Pause><Say>3</Say><Pause><Say>1`"

*How to convert this string to xml?*

Java code also helpful

Comment: If it is twirl try `@Html(body)`

Comment: @ajozwik i.e a xml file not html `twiml.scala.xml`

Comment: Which implementation do you use? Is it like playframework templates?

Comment: yeah! playframework template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this helps me.

```
@(body:String)
@import java.lang.String; var twiml=""
@{twiml="<Response><Say voice="alice">"+body+"</Say></Response>"}
@scala.xml.XML.loadString(twiml)
```

actually this was invalid

```
</Say><Pause><Say>3</Say><Pause><Say>1
```

thats why`@scala.xml.XML.loadString(body)` is not helping me